# ASP.NET Core detecting Mac OS user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cross-platform

I have created a .Net Core RC2 Web Application using VS2015 with windows authentication.

I then copied the project over to Mac OSX El Capitan and launched the app using the Terminal.

The application started as expected, however, as the application is running on my Mac there is no Windows user to display.

How can you return the Mac user and display the name?

This would also be useful for Linux users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To get the username of a user visited the website**

You may be thinking of the "Windows Authentication" feature of IIS. IIS does some magic to authenticate the user visiting the website against a Windows domain and then forwards that Windows auth token to ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core can only use this feature when hosted using IIS (or IIS Express) and using the IIS Integration middleware. See https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration. Because IIS is Windows only, this means it is not possible to get a client username when hosting the website on Linux or OSX.

**To get the username of the account hosting the web server**

As of .NET Core 1.0, there is no cross-platform API for getting a username directly. If you are on windows, `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` works, but this will throw `PlatformNotSupported` on Linux/macOS.

By convention, many systems set the username in an environment variable. You can use `System.Environment` to fetch this.

```
var username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") ??
               Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");
```

Another but more complicated approach is to p/invoke to native system calls that return information about the user, such as `getpwuid_r` (See the man pages for [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid_r) and [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getpwuid.3.html).)

Comment: To return a user for each OS you can also add in `User.Identity.Name` - `var username = User.Identity.Name ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") ??
               Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");`

Comment: @shammelburg I may have misunderstood your original intention. Do you want to get the username of the user in the browser? Or the username that is running the server?

Comment: I wanted to get the current logged in user.

Comment: @shammelburg as in the user that is visiting your website?

Comment: This application will be on an internal network. So getting the windows user is easy when on deployed on Windows, just wanted to get the Mac user.